# Remove sync user to harden the system

Tags: hardening, debian

I read a book about linux hardening (Hardening Linux by James Turnbull, 2005). The book suggests to remove the sync user. If I remove the sync user I am not able to call commands like `ls` and `shutdown`, because they are not found anymore.

I used the following command to remove the sync user:

```
userdel -r -f sync
```

The following error appears after I removed the user:

```
-bash: shutdown: command not found
```

why do these commands not work anymore? and is it possible to remove the sync user without any problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There is no user that is required to sync to the disk. The `sync()` and `fsync()` syscalls are _completely_ unprivileged. And `ls` doesn't call it anyway.

Comment: I mean the sync system user. If I remove the system user I am not able to call shutdown or ls.

Comment: What error do you get if you run `ls`? And a `sync` user is a [historical artifact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328117/277264) (like, from the 80s). It is not required to sync to the disk, it is designed to be a dummy user that someone can "log in with" using an empty password to sync the disk even if they do not have an account.

Comment: Please give the source where you've read it, including the year the book was published. Also cite the explanation the book gives why sync should be removed. And show how exactly you've removed the user.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated the question

Comment: Are you sure `ls` itself is actually not working? You must have a [really screwed up system](https://xkcd.com/1084/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> userdel -r -f sync

With the `-r` option you are not only removing the user but all data below the users home. On my system the users home is `/bin`:

```
$ grep ^sync: /etc/passwd
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
```

Only, `/bin` is the place where lots of essential binaries are stored. Thus, it is not surprising if essential functionality gets lost if you remove `/bin`.

> The book suggests to remove the sync user

That's an unusual recommendation. The usual recommendation is to disable shell access for system users like `sync` or `daemon` and lock these (i.e. no valid password) which usually is already done on common systems.

Comment: Ouch, good catch. I guess all that's left is for OP to reinstall.

Comment: very good hint thanks! So before I remove a user with `-r -f` I have to check where his/her/its home location is.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a newer linux hardening book?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is not a cleaner approach to remove unused/unnecessary users from a system?

Comment: @KevinWallis: why do you think so? You've seen where a too clean approach leads too :) Apart from that, it is better to run some process as a less privileged system user than have it run as root. And that's what these users are usually for.

Comment: @KevinWallis It all depends on the user. Simply removing users will not really affect the system's security at all. You have to do more than that. For example, removing the `audio` user and letting pulseaudio take care of audio can improve security a bit if done right, and removing the `video` user will greatly improve security, but will break hardware-accelerated video decoding and OpenGL.

Comment: *"do you have any suggestions for a newer linux hardening book?"* - no, but  if you want to have a more hardened UNIX system you might just have a look at OpenBSD instead :)